# Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Cursor<Object>'. Property 'count' is missing in type '{}[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, meteor

I am creating an angular application with meteor js.

I have a collection defined in collections/bookmark folder in my root directory outside client and server folder

`import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
const Bookmarks = new Mongo.Collection('bookmarks');
export default Bookmarks`

I am importing the Bookmarks into my component to display the records stored in the collections.. but console.log(Bookmarks.find().fetch()) is returning an empty array and assigning the result to the class variable giving me error **Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Cursor'.   Property 'count' is missing in type '{}[]'**

here is the code of my component :

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import Bookmarks from '../../../../collections/bookmarks';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './bookmarklist.html';


@Component({
selector: 'bookmark-list',
template: template
})
export class BookmarkList {

bookmarks : Mongo.Cursor<Object>;

constructor(){
          console.log(Bookmarks.find().fetch());
          this.bookmarks = Bookmarks.find().fetch();
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my meteor console where i have been able to fetch the records
[Meteor Mongo Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAPzg.png)

Comment: So do you think it might then be logical that the `.fetch()` does not in fact return a `Mongo.Cursor` like you are trying to assign to? Kind of is why you are using Typescript. Perhaps a new editor might help.

Comment: I was using .find() before as they said in the toturial but i have been told that i must use .find().fetch()..

using just .find() return this local collection and i have no idea what to do with this ....



`LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: null, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}`

Comment: It's an array of object. But again you're using TypeScript. And it's kind of pointless to do so unless you use an editor with linting support and is generally aware of the "types". It sounds like you are not, and therefore running into errors on tranpile that are easily avoided. So best to get a better editor.

Comment: I am using visual studio code

Comment: I got around it... Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its just an editor error! I have been able to fetch objects by adding records directly from the application rather then meteor console.